# Using the self calling function in jQuery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

## **Code**

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script>
var m = -1;
function start(){
    m++;

    if(m<7){
        $("#t"+m).animate({left: 950-m*50}, 2000, 'linear', (function(m){
            if(m==6)    $("#text_message").text("Well done!");
        })(m));
    }else{
        clearTimeout(set);
    }

    set=setTimeout("start();", 1000);
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="start();">

<div style="background: gray; width: 1000px; height: 50px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div id="t6" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t5" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t4" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: yellow; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t3" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: lime; position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t2" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue; position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: indigo; position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="t0" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: purple; position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="text_message" style=" position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 50px;">Not yet!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## **Description**

This is a simple example of jQuery `animate()` method.
I am trying to move all of the boxes to the right side.
But the problem I encountered is not the `animate()` method, it's the `text_message`.
I hope the `text_message` display "*Well done!*" after all of the boxes completely move to the right side.
Unfortunately, before all of the boxes completely move to the right side, it shows "*Well done!*" early.
How can I solve this problem? Is there any problem with using the self calling function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the complete callback as you did by creating that self-calling function.
Instead, you can use `this` to access the animated element within the function scope:

```
$("#t"+m).animate({left: 950-m*50}, 2000, 'linear', function(){
  var n = $(this).attr('id').split('t')[1];
  if(n == 6)
    $("#text_message").text("Well done!");
});
```

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/41gavzsx/1/

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @MorKadosh works well but remind to move the setTimeout method  to the beginning of the function or into the if clause because you currently have a endless loop.

You call in your else clearTimeout but set it afterwards again...

Answer (score 0):

I find my own solution for that ! create one more `setTimeout` is nice to me ,it should take 2 sec because u made 2 sec in your right move

```
function start(){
m++;

if(m<7){
    $("#t"+m).animate({left: 950-m*50}, 2000, 'linear', (function(m){
        if(m==6)   setTimeout(success,2000);
    })(m));
}else{
    clearTimeout(set);
}

set=setTimeout("start();", 1000);
}
function success(){
$("#text_message").text("Well done!");
}
```